# What is a client in network of Hyperledger fabric peers?

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger

What is a client in a network of Hyperledger fabric peer?

What is the role of a client?

What can qualify as a client in the  Hyperledger fabric blockchain network?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

have a look at this (and specifically, look into the Network Entities / Systems part):

https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/master/docs/glossary.md

I'm still rather new to this, but my understanding is that you have a) peers in a P2P network that can be either validator or non-validator - the latter existing mostly for performance purposes; and b) you have clients, who talk to peers in a client-server manner to issue queries and request transactions from the P2P network.

What can qualify as a client: basically anything that can talk to peers in this manner. (I think there are even some SDKs, but I'm concentrating on other aspects of Hyperledger, so I don't know yet.) Have a look at the IBM Marbles demo:

https://github.com/IBM-Blockchain/marbles

Comment: Currently, the "client" and server daemon are implemented in the same binary. There has been some discussion about separating out the client function, but we've not made progress on this as yet. 

There is currently a node.js SDK and discussion within the community of other language SDKs for Java and Python. Of course, being open source anyone may contribute towards developing an SDK in their preferred language.

Comment: @christo4ferris The client and server are in the same binary. What if I make another client in Java SDK? And if I can, how to create it in Java SDK? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

A client application talks to a peer over either REST or GRPC interface and submits transactions and queries to the peer to chaincodes.

Answer (score 0):

A client is an end user of the application. The client invokes the smart contract by placing a request on the channel. Each smart contract has a set of endorsing pairs required. The request is picked by the required endorsing peers and executed. The resulting read-write sets are sent back to the client.

Answer (score -2):

> **what is Client in Hyperledger** :

The Hyperledger Fabric **Client** SDK makes it easy to use **APIs** 
   to **interact with a Hyperledger** Fabric blockchain.

> **Features**:

*create a new channel*

send channel information to a peer to join

install chaincode on a peer

instantiate chaincode in a channel, which involves two steps: propose and transact

submitting a transaction, which also involves two steps: propose and transact

query a chaincode for the latest application state

various query capabilities:

logging utility with a built-in logger (winston)